# eclipse highlighting code partially

Tags: eclipse, gsp, spring-tool-suite

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27799014/error-highlight-in-eclipse-only-partially-works) but mine is different. Look at my screenshot:  [image]

Eclipse ( to be specific I am using Spring Tool Suite(**STS**)) stopped highlighting in the middle of the variable delet**edValues**.

I am checking if there is any possible error while it is doing so but can't explain why stopped highlighting right there.

Comment: Are you sure you are opening the file in a javascript editor? Also, take a look at the error log and paste any relevant exceptions.

Comment: this js code is with in GSP page ( I am on grails) and I dont see any error.

Comment: I haven't actually tried this out, but this may not be supported in GSP pages.